# Swift Codable: Decoding dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm trying to practice Swift's Codable API.
I send a network request and I receive one single line each time as follows where I have to deal with dynamic keys :

Response example 1:

```
{
  "EUR": 4695.01
}
```

Response example 2:

```
{
  "USD": 479.01
}
```

Response example 3:

```
{
  "BTC": 4735.01
}
```

I tried this method to parse the dynamic keys :

```
struct ConversionResponseModel: Decodable {
    typealias destinationCurrency = String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    }
}
```

and my fetching request :

```
do {
    let myResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(ConversionResponseModel.self, from: data)
                print(myResult)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

But I get this as a result : `ConversionResponseModel()`, but not the currency values.
It sounds like I'm missing something. Any help please. Thank you

Comment: If the keys are dynamic it's easier to decode `[String:Double]` or write a custom initializer to assign the key to a property `currency` and the value to a property `rate`

Comment: Since these are financial numbers to a specific number of decimal digits, I'd recommend `[String: Decimal]` here instead. You should be very careful about working with currencies as a Double; you'll get binary rounding errors far too often. (It's a bit unclear how careful Swift's JSONDecoder is about the String to Decimal conversion, so you should test carefully to look for rounding errors, but once in your system, currencies should always be Decimal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. The JSON you're getting will return a dictionary of `[String:Double]`. You can then covert that using:

```
struct ConversionResponseModel: Decodable {
    typealias DestinationCurrency = String
    
    let currency : DestinationCurrency
    let value : Double
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dict = try container.decode([String:Double].self)
        guard let key = dict.keys.first else {
            throw NSError(domain: "Decoder", code: 0, userInfo: [:])
        }
        currency = key
        value = dict[key] ?? -1
    }
}
```

*Note: taking into account Rob Napier's comment, you could substitute `Decimal` for `Double` -- see his comment on the original question for more detail*